# Content Security Policy directive while Calling JS funtion from rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using simple_form and slim template engine, and unable to call javascript function

```
= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Name', label: false, input_html: {:onclick => "search()"}
```

**Error** `Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

This below code is calling JS but not above one

```
= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Name', label: false, input_html: {class: 'find'}
```

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.find').on('click', function() {
        alert("class javascript");
    });

    function search() {
        alert("search from ready");
    }
});

function search() {
    alert("outer");
}
```

Help me out, How to call JS function search() from rails view.

Answer (score 0):

```
= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Name', label: false, :onclick => 'search();'
```

here you are calling search() function on click of this input field:

so you would need to define search function in js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function search(){
   alert("outer");
}
</script>
```

Comment: **Error** on code,  No opening {  found. but after removing it is also not working